# redefinition of ‘main’ ,,, previous definition of ‘main’ was here

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Ravi:NSObject
{
int a,b,c;
}
@property int a;
@property int b;
@property int c;
-(void)setValue:(int)x :(int)y;
-(int)getValue;
@end

@implementation Ravi
@synthesize a;
@synthesize b;
@synthesize c;

-(void)setValue:(int)x :(int)y
{
c = x + y;
}

-(int)getValue
{
NSLog(@"value of c is : %d",c);
return 0;
}
@end

int main()
{
Ravi * myobj=[[Ravi alloc]init];
[myobj setValue:23 :23];
[myobj getValue];
return 0;
}

@interface Krishna:NSObject
-(void)mymethod;
@end

@implementation Krishna
-(void)mymethod
{
Ravi * myobj=[[Ravi alloc]init];
myobj.a = 50;
myobj.b = 50;
myobj.c = myobj.a+myobj.b;
NSLog(@"krishna value of c is : %d",myobj.c);
}
@end

 int main()
 {
 Krishna * obj=[[Krishna alloc]init];
 [obj mymethod];
 return 0;
 }
```

I am trying to learn objective c and i don't have xcode on my PC. I fine this online objective c tutorial. I am using GNU GCC Version 4.7.2. when i am trying to call the variables of one class into another class . i get this error "redefinition of ‘main’"

Answer (score 2):

You have once defined `main()` to be

```
int main()
{
Ravi * myobj=[[Ravi alloc]init];
[myobj setValue:23 :23];
[myobj getValue];
return 0;
}
```

… and later you redefine it to be the following:

```
 int main()
 {
 Krishna * obj=[[Krishna alloc]init];
 [obj mymethod];
 return 0;
 }
```

Removing one of the instances should rid you of the compiler-error.

Comment: I didn't get you when you said to remove one of the instance? i am using two classes and calling variables from one class to another class. i got an output as 46 when i executed the "Ravi"class and i am expecting output as 100 when am calling "mymethod" in "Krishna" class.how ?

Comment: When the app runs, the first thing it does is call the function called `main`. When you have two, it don't know which one to run. Even though it's two different files, they are still compiled down into the same app.